# Unwanted logout when selecting data via console

Tags: mysql

I have imported web-scraped data into a table of a MySQL Database. The import worked fine (see
[Import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChuEW.png)).

When I am trying to display the data via `SELECT * FROM table4;` I get logged out of the console (see [logout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBbxZ.png) ).

However, when I am trying to display the data using `SELECT * FROM table4\G` it works like fine (see [\G](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsAWV.png)).

I am using MySQL Server 8.0 on my local Windows 10 Machine. Can anybody explain why this is happening? I have tried around a bit and it seems that issue is coming from the textlength. I have specified the data type as LONGTEXT. If a specify the data type as MEDIUMTEXT the error does not arise. I assume that is because some text is cut off. Encoding does not seem to be an issue.

Comment: Does some data in a table is binary? Have you specified correct charsets/collations? Firstly test `SELECT * FROM table4 ORDER BY some_column LIMIT some_value;` and find the row which causes the problem. Then investigate it by selecting `HEX(column)` and find the symbol/byte which causes the issue. *If a specify the data type as MEDIUMTEXT the error does not arise. I assume that is because some text is cut off.* Try to select some substring out of MEDIUMTEXT max. size.

Comment: hi @Akina, I managed to identify the row causing the issue. As soon as I split a certain amount into an extra row, it works like a charm. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Please compare ALL charsets and ALL collations on source and destination servers.